# What's your Objective-C coding style?

Tags: objective-c

The first thing I do when I incorporate any third party code into my application is reformat it to my personal coding preference:

```
// Single line comments only

// I never put spaces inside my parenthesis 
-(void)myOCDMethod
{    
    // If an if or for statement has only one instruction, I don't use brackets
    if(this)
        [self that];
    else
        [self somethingElse];

    // If I do have to use brackets, they go on their own lines so that they line up
    if(this)
    {
        [self that];
        [self andThat];
    }

    // I always put the pointer asterisk next to the instance name
    NSObject *variable = [[NSObject alloc] init];

    // I always put spaces around operators
    if(i == 0)
        x = 2;

}
```

What OCD coding format do you use?

Comment: Not using brackets also compiles a simpler instruction, I believe. Shouldn't be noticeable in a day to day basis, but it's always nice to know you're helping.
Why the single line comments?

Comment: Why can't the compiler perform that optimization on its own? Seems trivial...

Comment: (Same question applies to A ? B : C; )

Answer (score 3):

I do a lot of this, with a few differences:

I always insert spaces before and after parens:
 `-(void)myOCDMethod   ->   - (void) myOCDMethod`

I leave braces on the same line:

```
if (this) 
{
  //code
}
```

becomes

```
if (this) {
  //code
}
```

If I'm feeling particularly OCD, I'll line up my locals:

```
float                l1;
NSArray              *array;
ReallyLongClassName  *object;
```

And, finally, TABS, not SPACES.

Comment: If I don't do this, the day doesn't go right. Except for that lining up local, that's just crazy overkill.

Comment: No! Lining up locals and even ivars is the best! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Tabs are evil in a middle of a line, while spaces rock! Example:

```
int    n;
double d;
```

Let the tab size be 4. I'll point them out with dots:

```
.   .   .
int     n;  // two tabs here
double  d;  // one tab here
```

If that code is opened on another developer's machine, where tab size is 2, he'll see the following picture:

```
. . . . .
int   n;
double  d;
```

So, you should either use same tab size (and this would not work anyways, since your code may be reused by anybody in the world - you can't force everybody), or stick to spaces. Gotcha?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same as yours, though I leave a space between the "-" or "+" and the opening parenthesis of the return type. Oh, and I use the (condition) ? (value1) : (value2) thing a lot, mainly for assignments and math... I know it makes the code harder to read, but it saves three lines' worth of typing.

Comment: Plus, it has less overhead (I don't know if it's noticeable, though).

Answer (score 0):

1. Indent the code properly
2. Correct line breaks. (Max one line break; line break before every function and comment etc.)
3. Correct naming conventions

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the

```
NSString*  aString;
```

camp, rather than

```
NSString  *aString;
```

(For both variables and arguments)

The rationale being that in the first case, it looks like it's saying "aString is an NSString pointer", while the latter reads more like "(the dereferenced) *aString is an NSString object". Especially in Obj-C, where all the objects are heap-allocated and hence refered to by pointers, the first one feels less convoluted.

I only align curly braces for function definitions, methos definitions and ivar blocks, because those are first-level scopes in the file (anything outside is global) and feels 'leaky' otherwise. Aligned, the block is more discernible, without 'holes'.

In method signatures, I use this spacing:

```
- (void) methodName:(Class*) object;
```

I like to align the colons vertically when there is more than 2 arguments (unless the first param tag is much longer than the method name, when it breaks). Xcode nicely auto-tabs to this.

Everything else is like you.

Comment: You are welcome to comment on why a specific coding style (essentially, a matter of taste) deserves a downvote.